# Какие данные компоненты относяться к модели, а какие нет?

Tags: javascript, mvc, backbone.js

У меня есть компонент с настройками. Он содержит 4 item`а.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Каждый item это тоже компонент - SettingRange. Как видно каждый из них имеет следующие данные:
title - заголовок настройки
min - минимальное значение
max - максимальное значение
from - положение левого ползунка
to - положение правого ползунка

Вопрос в том какие из этих данных будут данными модели компонента SettingRange, а какие нет. min, max, from, to думаю нам подходят, ибо их мы шлем в запросе на сервер и получаем соответсвующие данные. А вот насчет title я не уверен. Тем более что проект мультиязычный и значение должно меняться в зависимости от локали пользователя. Да и зачем его хранить в модели, ведь он не где на сервере не хранится, ни как не меняется, ни куда не отправляется. И если title не должен хранится в модели то как его лучше передвать во View?

Comment: [tsya.ru](http://tsya.ru/)

Answer (score 2):

Заголовок компонента - это данные в чистом виде. Однако, не все данные необходимо хранить в модели. Основное предназначение модели - хранение *интерактивных* данных, которые меняются как клиентом, так и сервером, а так же - реализация бизнес-логики.

Тайтл - это статические данные, которые передаются в шаблон лишь на этапе создания представления компонента и не меняются на протяжении его жизни, а значит - он не участвует в дальнейшей его работе.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю как-то так

```js
var clsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    from: 0,
    to: 0
  }
});

var model = new clsModel();

var view = new SettingView({
  
  // Здесь передаем тайтл
  title: 'My title',
  
  // Здесь передаем данные для постройки ползунков
  model: model
});
```

Т.е тайтл никоим образом не относится к данным. Кстати, думаю что min и мах тоже не должны быть в модели. Возможно стоило бы переделать так

```js
var clsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
        from: 0,
        to: 0
      }
    });

var model = new clsModel();

var view = new SettingView({
      
  // Здесь передаем тайтл и граничные условия
  title: 'My title',
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
      
  // Здесь передаем данные для постройки ползунков
  model: model
});
```